# How do I find my file which was moved without destination

Tags: files, mv

I am in a trouble. I pressed 'enter'  without the destination. I had two files in the same directory with a common IDENTIFIER in their name. I wanted to move them to a folder, so I entered

mv /path/to/file/IDENTIFIER*

But before I enter destination I pressed 'enter'  and one of my file disappeared which was alphabetically higher.. Now I can not find that file anywhere. I was in my

Abhishek@abhishek$ directory in the terminal.

Can anyone give me an elaborate answer about how I can find or is it overwritten by the other file. I am a complete rookie in the Linux world but I know the workhow of the terminal. So I can do some basic commands.

Answer (score 7):

If you have only two files, eg:

```
IDENTIFIER_1
IDENTIFIER_2
```

then you have overwritten `IDENTIFIER_2` with the content of `IDENTIFIER_1`.

Example:

```
$ cat IDENTIFIER_1
IDENTIFIER_1

$ cat IDENTIFIER_2
IDENTIFIER_2

$ ls -og IDENTIFIER_*
-rw-rw-r-- 1  0 Mai 19 18:28 IDENTIFIER_1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 13 Mai 19 18:27 IDENTIFIER_2

$ mv IDENTIFIER_*

$ ls -og IDENTIFIER_*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 13 Mai 19 18:30 IDENTIFIER_2

$ cat IDENTIFIER_2 
IDENTIFIER_1
```

---

If you had had more than two files, then would be an error:

```
$ ls -og IDENTIFIER_*
-rw-rw-r-- 1  0 Mai 19 18:28 IDENTIFIER_1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 13 Mai 19 18:27 IDENTIFIER_2
-rw-rw-r-- 1  0 Mai 19 18:28 IDENTIFIER_3

$ mv IDENTIFIER_*
mv: target ‘IDENTIFIER_3’ is not a directory
```

For an even better explanation see [@Serg](https://askubuntu.com/a/625799/367165).

Comment: One of the tricks that I learned from years ago, to move the contents into `mkdir z; mv *` which moves everything into the directory `z`... of course, assuming that the `z` directory is the last item in the `*` expansion.

Comment: Sounds dangerous :)

Comment: You could always touch a file named `-i` if you are worried about that.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to merely expand on the answer that A.B. posted.

The wildcard merely expands IDENTIFIER_* to all instances of IDENTIFIER_*. Therefore, `mv IDENTIFIER_*` in  reality is read as `mv IDENTIFIER_1 IDENTIFIER_2`.

This is a same reason why for loops work like so `for file in *; do` , as well as `echo IDENTIFIER_*`, and so on and so forth.

Now the reason why 3 files dont work is again because the command `mv IDENTIFIER_*` expands to `mv IDENTIFIER_1 IDENTIFIER_2 IDENTIFIER_3`, and you are confusing `mv` with too many arguments.

[image]

Comment: I should delete my answer =) +1

Comment: no, no, don't delete it. It's still shows everything correctly

Answer (score 1):

You overwrote the second file with the first one.

It's lost unless you unmount  immediately the partition/device and try to recover it with a tool like **testdisk**, **photorec**, **extundelete**, or whatever.